# XQuery elements grouped by tags

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

Having this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<productos>
<TITULO>DATOS DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS</TITULO>
<producto>
    <cod_prod>1010</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26</denominacion>
    <precio>50</precio>
    <stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>3</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1011</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5-2320</denominacion>
    <precio>120</precio>
    <stock_actual>3</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1012</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5 2500</denominacion>
    <precio>170</precio>
    <stock_actual>5</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>6</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>20</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1013</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>HD Seagate Barracuda 250GB SATA</denominacion>
    <precio>80</precio>
    <stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>20</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1014</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>HD Caviar Blue 500GB SATA3</denominacion>
    <precio>150</precio>
    <stock_actual>5</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>6</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>30</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1015</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Tarjeta gráfica Asus GeForce EN210 Silent 1GB</denominacion>
    <precio>40</precio>
    <stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>30</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1016</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Tarjeta gráfica Gigabyte GeForce 1GB</denominacion>
    <precio>50</precio>
    <stock_actual>5</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>6</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>40</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1017</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Tarjeta gráfica Nvidia Express 1GB</denominacion>
    <precio>45</precio>
    <stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>30</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1018</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Micro Intel Dual Core G620</denominacion>
    <precio>60</precio>
    <stock_actual>15</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>40</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1019</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 2GB</denominacion>
    <precio>10</precio>
    <stock_actual>5</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>3</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
      <cod_prod>1020</cod_prod>
      <denominacion>Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 4GB</denominacion>
      <precio>30</precio>
      <stock_actual>30</stock_actual>
      <stock_minimo>10</stock_minimo>
      <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <cod_prod>1021</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Memoria DDR3 Kingston HyperX 4GB</denominacion>
    <precio>16</precio>
    <stock_actual>15</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>4</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>20</cod_zona>
  </producto>
  <producto>
  <cod_prod>1022</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Placa Base ASRock G41M-S3 </denominacion>
    <precio>52</precio>
    <stock_actual>2</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>2</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>30</cod_zona>
  </producto>
</productos>
```

I would like puting the 'productos' whose 'denominacion' is the same inside of tags. For example:

```
<placas> Placa Base MSI G41M-P26 Placa Base ASRock G41M-S3 </placas>
<micros> Micro Intel Core i5-2320 Micro Intel Core i5 2500 Micro Intel Dual Core G620 </micros>
```

Except for the ones which start with 'HD' and 'Tarjeta' (which have to be inside the tag: 'otros').
Here is a sample of what I have done:

```
for $productos in doc("productos.xml")/productos/producto
let $agrupacion := $productos/substring-before(data(denominacion),' ')
group by $agrupacion
order by $agrupacion
return if (contains($agrupacion,'Placa'))
then <placa>{data($productos/denominacion)}</placa>
else if (contains($agrupacion,'Micro'))
then <micro>{data($productos/denominacion)}</micro>
else if (contains($agrupacion,'Memoria'))
then <memoria>{data($productos/denominacion)}</memoria>
else <otros>{data($productos/denominacion)}</otros>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following uses a simple function to map the denominacion to a string/element name and then does the grouping:

```
declare function local:map ($denominacion as xs:string) as xs:string {
  if (contains($denominacion, 'Placa'))
  then 'placa'
  else if (contains($denominacion, 'Memoria'))
  then 'memoria'
  else if (contains($denominacion, 'Micro'))
  then "micro"
  else 'otros'
 };

for $producto in /productos/producto
group by $denominacion := local:map($producto/denominacion)
order by $denominacion
return element {$denominacion} {$producto/denominacion/data()}
```

that way I get

```
<memoria>Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 2GB Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 4GB Memoria DDR3 Kingston HyperX 4GB</memoria>
<micro>Micro Intel Core i5-2320 Micro Intel Core i5 2500 Micro Intel Dual Core G620</micro>
<otros>HD Seagate Barracuda 250GB SATA HD Caviar Blue 500GB SATA3 Tarjeta gráfica Asus GeForce EN210 Silent 1GB Tarjeta gráfica Gigabyte GeForce 1GB Tarjeta gráfica Nvidia Express 1GB</otros>
<placa>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26 Placa Base ASRock G41M-S3 </placa>
```

Comment: It would be nice if each group were inside their respective tags.

Comment: I have added the result I get, if that is not what you want then edit your question to explain and show in detail which result you want.